# CKEditor for Sharepoint 2007

Tags: ckeditor, sharepoint-2007

I'm interested in integrating CKEditor into Sharepoint 2007.

I have found tons of links to CKEditor, which leads to http://ckeditor.com/sharepoint but it seems that this link is not working any more.

Do you have information how to integrate that?

Answer (score 0):

The product was removed from the ckeditor.com website because it is no longer actively maintained. It is still possible to get a license (it has always been a commercial product, not an Open Source one, mind you), but you would need to [contact CKSource](http://cksource.com/contact) for that. Here is some documentation for it: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_SharePoint